# How can I get the Avatar Awards from Xbox Live Destination Arcade?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I've downloaded Destination Arcade, but when I launch it, my only option is to return to the Dashboard.  How can I get the Avatar awards from Destination Arcade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All my research seems to show that it has been disabled, and you can't actually get the rewards from it anymore.

From [AvatarAwards](http://avatarawards.ninjasfate.com/xbla/a-e/destination-arcade/):

> I believe Destination Arcade has been disabled making it impossible to
>   get the Avatar Awards right now.
>
> There is always a chance it will come back if Microsoft decide the
>   Beta got enough attention to keep working on it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to launch the game if you have not patched it. The last patch is supposed to have disabled the game. Try clearing your update cache (should be an option on your main storage drive) and launching it again. The go and see if you can run it and get the avatar award.

Comment: Can you tell me more about how to remove the update?  I had a poke at this; but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: There are two kinds of updates. Some go into the general update cache and the others are saved in the same directory as the game data. For the update cache, select the drive you are using for the game and bring up the options. Then choose to empty the update cache. Otherwise, go to Games > Destination Arcade and choose the item labeled "update", then delete.

Comment: Hrm, I couldn't get any of this to work - there was no "Options" for the game.

Comment: @KatieK Select the volume the game is on and press <kbd>Y</kbd> to bring up the volume options.